# Enumerating how many ways two sets of symbols can be written in order.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that I have two ordered tuples of symbols $A = (a_1,\ldots,a_m)$ and $B = (b_1,\ldots, b_n)$. Using each of the symbols in $A$ and $B$ once and only once, we can form words of length $m+n$ with the condition that the symbols from each of $A$ and $B$ appear in the correct order. For example,
$$
a_1 \cdots a_m b_1 \cdots b_n, \qquad a_1 \cdots a_{m-1}b_1 a_m b_2 \cdots b_n, \quad \text{and} \quad b_1\ldots b_n a_1 \cdots a_m
$$
are all valid words. Let $\Sigma(m,n)$ denote the total number of words of this allowed form.

For example $\Sigma(m,1) = m+1$ since we can slot the single element of $B$ at the start or end of the string of elements $a_1 \cdots a_m$ or anywhere in between two elements. We have $\Sigma(2,2) = 6$ with allowable strings
$$
a_1a_2b_1b_2 \quad a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2 \quad b_1a_1a_2b_2 \quad a_1 b_1 b_2 a_2 \quad b_1a_1b_2a_2 \quad b_1b_2 a_1a_2.
$$
Is there a "nice" way to compute $\Sigma(m,n)$? In particular, is there a way of expressing $\Sigma(m,n)$ in terms of $\Sigma(k,l)$ for $k < m$ and $l < n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice way is $$\binom{m+n}{m},$$ and the recurrence you seek is known as "Pascal's Triangle".

(proof of former): Once you pick the subset of $m$ letters out of $m+n$ there is only one way to slot in $A$ there and $B$ into the other one.

Comment: Oh boy I feel a fool. I really wasn't thinking about the total number of available spaces. Thanks!

Comment: @Zorngo all of us who do mathematics feel like fools.

Answer (score 1):

Think if it this way.  You have $m+n$ spaces.  You have to reserve $m$ of them for for then elements of $A$. Once you choose the $m$ spaces everything else is fixed and determined. The elements of $A$ must be in order in those spaces and the elements of $B$ must be in the remaining places in order.

So....

> Choosing $m$ spaces out of $m+n$ spaces is ${n+m \choose m}$